# Why is my Redirect 301 not working?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I already have a couple of rules set up such as

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.pipcanadaltd\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .?$ http://ca.pipglobal.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And I also have rewrites for a few PHP pages such as:

```
RewriteRule ^products/eye-protection-experts/$ prod-expert-eyewear.php [NC,L]
```

For some reason, when I went to create a simpler 301 redirect, it is not working. Here is what I have:

```
RewriteRule ^products/construction-channel-experts/$ ^products/construction-safety-solutions/ [R=301]
```

I'm really confused on why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule for `301` redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^products/construction-channel-experts/?$ /products/construction-safety-solutions/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Note that `^` is used for matching start position in regex and it can only be used in pattern which is on left hand side.

You should keep redirect rules before internal rewrite rules.

Comment: Ok I've tried this but I still get a 404 so there may be a config issue.

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^products/construction-channel-experts/?$ products/construction-safety-solutions/ [R=301,L,NC]` (assuming you have `RewriteBase` defined above)